# Ruby libary to DLL file for use it with C# asp.net

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ironruby

i want to use this Ruby code  https://github.com/weppos/freeagent
and convert it to Dll file or to any thing that allow my to use it in C#

any one can help me to convert it to Dll or EXE

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this is a good idea - but if you really need to use this Ruby code from .NET then check these out:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IronRuby_cSharp.aspx
- [Call Ruby or Python API in C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684145/call-ruby-or-python-api-in-c-net/1684954#1684954)
- http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Blog/From-C-to-Ruby-and-back-again-The
- http://www.igvita.com/2007/04/23/invoking-ruby-in-c-net/

these describe possible ways to achieve what you ask...

But since the [API is REST-/XML-based](http://www.freeagentcentral.com/developers/freeagent-api#api_attachments) I would recommend implementing it in C# - this way you have all options regarding updates/modifications etc. and I would definitely suspect even better performance...